# Error 404 Page Not Found after submitting form

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
controller -
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('News_model');
         $this->load->helper('url_helper');

    }
public function create(){

        echo $data['title']=$data['title1'] = 'Form';
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');
        $this->load->view('news/create', $data);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
           // $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            //$this->load->view('news/create');
          //  $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
        else
        {
            $this->news_model->set_news();
            $this->load->view('news/success');
        }
    }
}

?>

view-
<h2><?php echo $title1; ?></h2>
<?php echo validation_errors(); 
$this->load->helper('form'); ?>
<?php echo form_open(); ?>


 <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />

</form>

model-
<?php

class News_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){

        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function getnews($slug= FALSE){

        if($slug ===  FALSE){

                $query = $this->db->get('news');
                return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news' , array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
?>
```

Getting error - 404 Page Not Found while submitting form on localhost.After Submitting form link looks like this - http://localhost/ci/index.php/news/localhost/ci/index.php/news/create

Getting error - 404 Page Not Found while submitting form on localhost.After Submitting form link looks like this - http://localhost/ci/index.php/news/localhost/ci/index.php/news/create

Comment: what is your `base_url`... you can see issue just by looking at url.

Comment: it's $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/ci/'

Comment: then i don't see a reason why it would repeat that 2 times

Comment: After submitting form,it happens like this..http://localhost/ci/index.php/news/localhost/ci/index.php/news/create

Comment: try setting base url to `http://localhost/ci/`

Comment: try it with root '/ci/controller/method'

Comment: Thanks Alex , it worked with http.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the below steps:**

**1.** You need to load 'url_helper' in autoload file and its a best practice instead of writing in every page. *path(application > config > autoload.php)*

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**2.** You need to add below line in top of the view page.

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
```